# Efficient C++11 design for event listener with a regular wake-up?

Tags: multithreading, events, c++11, future, latency

**The Problem**

I've a system (using C++11) with a producer of irregular events: `P` (e.g. it could be UI events, or it could be receiving financial trade data over a TCP/IP socket, etc.) Each event comes with a small packet of data.

Then I have a number of "worker bees": `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, ... Each of these does their own processing of the events that `P` feeds them. Their processing might be quick, but might take a long time, which is why the plan is to run each worker bee in its own thread. In addition each of the worker bees need to run a different function every N seconds (e.g. N=60, but again it can vary by worker bee). This regular processing should always be done in serial with the event processing, never on a different thread.

Finally, some of the worker bees might also get events from other producers (`P2`, `P3`, etc.) However if that complicates things I can always have `P1`, `P2`, etc feed to a central `P` whose job is to send all events to the worker bees.

**The Question**

What is the best design for such a system? Low latency and efficiency are the main criteria for *best*. Reliability is also important though: every `B` must receive every event (even if they come through as a batch because it was busy at the time), and if one `B` crashes it should not affect the others.

If it matters: assume 1-64 worker bees, 4-8 hardware threads, average time between events is 10 seconds, minimum time between events is 0.2 seconds, and the typical regular function is every `N=60` seconds. But if the ideal design is sensitive to any of those criteria I'd like to understand how.

NOTE: If the worker bees can guarantee never to throw an exception, does that change the choice of best design? (It feels like that will be unrelated, but I thought I'd bring it up.)

NOTE: there may be more bees than hardware threads; assume that is a problem for another time. (E.g. latency may matter for some worker bees and they may be given their own threads, whereas others may be told to share a thread.)

**Idea One: wait until event or timeout**

Each `P` has a mutex and a condition. When it gets new data it signals the condition.

Each worker bee uses `theCondition.wait_until(lock,timeout)` where `timeout` is the time it next needs to wake up to do its regular processing. It checks the return value to see if it was signalled, or timed-out.

The downside here seems to be that it is just a signal, no data. So I'd need each `B` to get another lock for read access to the data queue. And typically they'll all want to do that at the same time, so this gets ugly.

I'm also not clear what happens if one `B` takes a long time processing something and misses a couple of events before it gets around to calling `wait_until` again.

**Idea Two: per-worker data queue**

Here each `B` has a queue, with a lock. `P` gets a write lock, and adds a data item. `B` gets a read lock to pop each item off when it is ready. I still need some way for `B` to know to wake-up because there is new data.

The downside here seems to be the `P` thread needs to loop through each `B` to give them data. That introduces latency, and also feels fragile (e.g. if one of the worker bees is behaving badly).

**Idea Three: futures**

This problem feels like a good fit for futures.  `P` creates a `std::promise`, then each `B` gets a `std::future` (a `std::shared_future`, I assume). As `P` receives a new event it calls `set_value()` on the promise. Each `B` is calling `wait_until` on its future.

This appeals as the signal and the data come together. Also there is no locking, so it should be resilient.

The bit I'm stuck with is that the promise/future is a one-bullet gun. I need to create a new set of promise/shared_future pairs immediately after each new event. How could that even work? (Could I pass the next `shared_future` as part of the data being sent by the `set_value` call?) Is there any chance of an event being missed by any of the workers if two events come through in quick succession?

Comment: +1, well-posed interesting question. Reliability is a tough one. You're going to have a hard time recovering (safely) from a crashed thread. The ideal architecture I'd go with for this is a lock-free queue of events (filled by `P`) and a semaphore of the number of items available in it that the worker bees would wait on (with a timeout to handle the self-injected events). Unfortunately, I don't know of any lightweight semaphore implementation (that's both fast when there's many items and no waiting needs to be done, and that blocks the thread at the OS level when there aren't any items).

Comment: lightweight semaphore: spinlock wrapped around a mutex/cond pair. or, use linux because synchronization primitives are based on futexes, only slow when it needs to block.

Comment: [rxcpp](http://rxcpp.codeplex.com/) is a quite full-featured event processing framework.

Comment: [Full code you can play with here](http://pastebin.com/kQzEV1gK)

Comment: The above code still has at least one bug: regular not called when too busy. Will post another code after some time. But you can play with the first one already.

Comment: [Idea1/Opt4 Full Code](http://pastebin.com/cSFs0V5Q) ...growing and bee management omitted.

Comment: I now have a proof-of-concept of my option 3, which I'll post as a self-answer soon-ish.

Comment: Judging the difference between the answers is a bit beyond me (we really need to find a good way to benchmark), so I'm going to award the bounty to firda, mainly for posting full code that we can experiment with.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. Try using different queues (you can see two of them in my code - std::queue with custom locking and boost::lockfree ... but you may also try [Intel Thread Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/). It is hard to select the one if we don't know how many bess and how busy they will be (simple solution may be better for few bees and quick work, while different for heavy parallel work). Good luck.

Comment: Think about using [spinlocks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_spinlock) or [std::atomic_flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) (test_and_set for try-lock, clear for unlock). Good for pairing with lockree queue or to avoid heavy-locking (that is what I was trying to achieve - design for many bees with small job). For few bees and/or heavy work in each, use simple solution (e.g. the one from Rumburak), should be fine ;)

Comment: [See my revised code](http://pastebin.com/1WzLV43T) if you really want fast (and mad) implementation (instead of simple and working for sure). This one was designed with spin-locking in mind. Should avoid locking 99.99% of the time and solve the rest by spin-lock-like approach. Looks like I am really mad :D P.S.: tabstop=4

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you can benefit form the producer-consumer pattern. Here is an example of this using boost libraries and a lockfree queue (from boost), just change the type that it is operating on:

```
boost::atomic_int producer_count(0);
boost::atomic_int consumer_count(0);

boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue(128);

const int iterations = 10000000;
const int producer_thread_count = 4;
const int consumer_thread_count = 4;

void producer(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != iterations; ++i) {
       int value = ++producer_count;
        while (!queue.push(value))
            ;
    }
}

boost::atomic<bool> done (false);
void consumer(void)
{
    int value;
    while (!done) {
        while (queue.pop(value))
            ++consumer_count;
    }

    while (queue.pop(value))
        ++consumer_count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "boost::lockfree::queue is ";
    if (!queue.is_lock_free())
        cout << "not ";
    cout << "lockfree" << endl;

    boost::thread_group producer_threads, consumer_threads;

    for (int i = 0; i != producer_thread_count; ++i)
        producer_threads.create_thread(producer);

    for (int i = 0; i != consumer_thread_count; ++i)
        consumer_threads.create_thread(consumer);

    producer_threads.join_all();
    done = true;

    consumer_threads.join_all();

    cout << "produced " << producer_count << " objects." << endl;
    cout << "consumed " << consumer_count << " objects." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As each of my worker bees needs to be given the same data, this sounds like a variation of my Idea Two, with a `boost::lockfree::queue` for each `B`? How can each `B` be told to "wake-up there is new data"?

Comment: @DarrenCook Each worker would get its own queue, and when the queue is empty it could either sleep and check or wait on its own signal triggered by the producers. I would recommend using Boost.Signals to multi-cast a producer event to the workers, and passing ref counted references and not copies of the event data, to reduce memory used.

Answer (score 3):

I start with some critique of the options so far and propose another one below:

### Your Idea One:

My main problem with this is that you're talking of a single data queue. Since *every* Bee needs to process *every* event, you need to somehow keep track of how many Bees have seen each event in order to be able to finally discard the data from the queue.

You could of course associate each item in the queue with an atomic countdown variable. The Bee that sets the counter to zero also removes the event from the queue. But atomic counters aren't free of cost. And you have to be /really/ careful how to decrease the counter and check for zero in a way that you're sure that exactly one Bee removes the event from the queue, see below for the potential race condition.

And you cannot really use a normal queue, because if one Bee is lagging behind, the events do not get removed and the other Bees cannot start working on new incoming events unless they somehow know how many items to skip. And how can they know that? They would have to store some kind of pointer or an index of the latest event they processed.

And you cannot add or remove Bees at runtime, since that would mess with the counter logic to delete events from the queue.

And Bees simply must not crash because that again would mess with the counter logic.

*Remark:* This would be different, btw, if your program does not run very long and you could afford to store the events until the end of the lifetime of the program in a huge vector for instance. Then each Bee would just have to keep an index of the last event it processed. In the following, I'll assume that you have to delete event data after processing it.

### Your Idea Two:

Sure, there is the overhead of copying every event to every queue, but you wrote that events are small. Compared with the problems of a single queue, that seems a small price.

Regarding the locks you mentioned, the lockfree queue allows you to get rid of those as mentioned by wbennett and firda.

You still have to somehow solve the question of how to manage calling the regular heartbeat.

### Your Idea Three:

IMO, Promise/Future do not help at all here, because you still have to be able to queue them up somehow if a Bee lags behind. So you're back to having queues, but this time with more complex structures that come with their own additional overhead.

### firda's Option One:

My main objection is the usage of one queue with all the drawbacks described above.

Also, in order to reduce the latency to a minimum, you'll have to reduce the sleep time to a minimum. So basically you'll have a busy-wait. Sure, different sleep times /might/ distribute, the load, but there is not guarantee for that.

### firda's Option Two:

Sorry, if I misinterpreted earlier versions.

To be honest, I can't say whether the current version (posted at http://pastebin.com/Y7M56Mtm) is correct or not. The reason is the sheer number of variables used for deciding whether to sleep, to pop, or to do the regular work.

In addition to the queue (with its own mutex), the condition variable, the mutex and and some timing information, you have

- n - basically a counter of elements in the queue
- was_empty - an indicator that the producer found an empty queue when pushing
- wakeup - an indicator that the producer wants to wakeup the bee

IMHO, none of those additional variables should be necessary. The size of the queue should be sufficient. That synchronization code has a complexity that I would not want to review. Unless you have mad multithreading skills (I certainly don't), I'd strongly advice to drop attempts to be smart about this.

So maybe it is correct, maybe not, I don't know :-)

### wbennett's proposal:

As you can probably tell from the stuff above, having one queue per Bee would be my preference. I don't think that lockfree offers much benefit though, see below.

It does not mention how to solve the regular method call, though.

### My proposal:

I posted my proposal in a second answer because the reviews in this text have seen so many revisions and comments and discuss stuff that gets outdated all the time.

Comment: 1. You are correct that I should use different method in my `pop()`, the decrement has to take place before calling inner `q.pop()`, this can probably be achieved by two atomic counters (will think and rewrite it if I can). 2. I have missed the point of bees consuming same event - that would lead to multiple queues again... but... well I have to think about that again.

Comment: I have one objection: why using lockfree queues when we have to use timed_mutex+condition_variable or semaphore to signal empty/non-empty state? That is why I offered my atomic counter (see update, this one should work).

Comment: @firda, right now, your new solution increases n in push() and pop(). That's probably not what you wanted? (sorry, cannot comment on your post directly, missing 14 point to gain that right). I tried replacing one by n--, but I am pretty sure it still allowing race conditions.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. Corrected. I am pretty sure it can be done this way and quite sure this one is correct (with --n in pop()). See the comments, the error was in mixing conditions (not using `n` for checking if queue is empty). Now it has to work. Try to find the race condition if you can, please.

Comment: I can see only one possible problem of my reviewed solution: correctly implementing `wait_handle` like Windows AutoResetEvent - producer can call `notify()` before consumer calls `wait()`. But that can be solved (`mutex`, `condition_variable` and flag).

Comment: +1: spotted my errors = four to go (for comments everywhere) ;)

Comment: @firda, added a review of your new option 2. The race condition is still there, I am afraid. Thanks for the +1, though :-)

Comment: Cannot see it: you started with bad precondition: non-empty queue but somebody waiting. Cannot happen. Circular proof is invalid (you already started with what you are trying to proove).

Comment: I have added my notes on my answer. I repeat that I have missed the condition of **every event reaching every bee** at first. My original opt2 was for load-balancing (event consumed by first available bee). The reviewed version works for both (load-balancing and multiple-queue per bee). The original (with the bug) actually worked for per-bee-queue as well.

Comment: @firda, I rewrote the race condition analysis. You wouldn't even get away with it with one Bee per queue, but that's a bit harder to show since you did not add the code which puts the Bee to sleep. See my remark on my own solution. BTW: You are missing still missing the regular function call :-)

Comment: I am giving up with those counters (problem is I cannot test_and_decrement_if_non_zero as atomic operation). It is not worth it (mutex would do just well). Regular function was ment to be called through computing the timeout. Well, I have learned a lesson: do not try to write synchronization primitives yourself! :D

Comment: Thanks for comparing each option. Regarding your worries about queue size, the assumptions say there is an average of 600 events/hour, so memory usage of the queues (I was thinking std::vector with an index, actually, when I said "data queue") is unlikely to be a concern. (And you now should have the rep to comment anywhere ;-)

Comment: @Rumburak: Your race conditions were correct for multiple-consumer, but not for single-consumer (problem was in pop, not in push). Nevermind, here is my third version with all the detail (all contained `wait_for` to include regular). Regular should now be called when pop() returns false.

Comment: @firda, Honestly, I lost track of all the different versions. I was sure your original Option Two was multiple consumers. Sorry, if I misinterpreted it. One learning for me is each option should be given as an individual answer. It would have made it much easier to comment on each one (if you have enough points to do so).

Comment: @Rumburak: I got it bad the first time (load-balancing), my mistake. Then I updated the answer and you probably didn't read it (it was there since first review). I am working on the code for opt2 now (found minor bug with regular not being called when too busy in first full code).

Comment: @firda Thanks for letting me know, I'll take a look tomorrow :-)

Comment: @Rumburak: [done for today](http://pastebin.com/Y7M56Mtm) (how nasty the threads can be, had to use priority_queue/heap for missed elements in bees for check that I got them all... but looks good, number of threads increasing, everything consumed as should be, regular called fine. both locking and lockfree queues).

Comment: @Rumburak: It was just fun for me, learning by trial and error. I have some skills with microprocessors - synchronization of interrupt with main loop (advantages: interrupt is automatically *locked* = uninterruptible by main loop, single-producer single-consumer scenairo, but load-store architecture often needs more attention). I was not trying to be smart, but try to solve interesting synchronization problem. I am currently writing pure C++11 middle-server with possibly many many threads, clients, connections... some thoughts can be used (and probably the reason for load-balancing at first).

Comment: @Rumburak: Locking the whole queue would work without my counter and flags, but what about lockfree queue(s)? I was trying to keep the advantage :)

Comment: @firda It is quite possible that your code works as expected, but I really can't tell (at least not within a few hours). Unless there is a really hard performance requirement (and you cannot gain performance much easier in other places), I would try to keep the synchronization logic simple. Your server might be such an example, of course. And yes, it has been fun to be part of the trial and error :-)

Comment: @Rumburak: I was tempted to use multiple locks and whatever in my link-server, but finally ended with one global read-write-lock (shared mutex) and one helper: auto_lock - lock()/shared() any number of times, relock() (shared->unique), unlock() or destruction in any state - not recursive, simple marking of shared/unique code, big loops with auto.unlock() on top. That is all ;)

Comment: @Rumburak: I was talking about configuration/state management (user, units and whatever objects and lists). I use other mutexes for client queues and such.

Comment: @Rumburak the lock-free queue would be necessary for multiple writers writing to a single worker, if events came from two sources simultaneously.

Comment: I've added an answer showing how to use std::future. The queueing just happened naturally, I didn't need to do anything explicit. Also no explicit synchronization primitives were needed. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3):

With the additional information from Darren's comment (memory is of no concern) we do not need one queue per bee. Instead, we can put events into a single vector or (if you're sure that Bees cannot lag behind too much) a reasonably sized fixed array. And then

- Use an atomic counter for the index of the latest event.
- Each Bee has its own index
- Use the synchronization technique as described here http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html where

  - the vector is the queue
  - empty = bee.index == producer.index

This is what it looks like:

```
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

struct event{};

constexpr size_t size = 65536;

std::array<event, size> queue;
std::mutex m;
std::atomic<size_t> queue_index;
std::condition_variable cv;

struct bee
{
  using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  using timestamp = std::chrono::time_point<clock>;

  int _heartbeat_seconds;
  timestamp _until;
  size_t _index;

  bee(int heartbeat_seconds):
    _heartbeat_seconds(heartbeat_seconds),
    _until(clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(_heartbeat_seconds)),
    _index(0)
  {}

  void run()
  {
    while(true)
    {
      // Wait until either an event is available or the regular call is due
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        while(_index != queue_index and clock::now() >= _until)
        {
          cv.wait_until(lock, _until);
        }
      }

      // Perform regular call and process events until your out of work
      if (clock::now() >= _until)
        regular();

      while (_index != queue_index)
      {
        ++_index;
        _index = _index % size;

        const auto& e = queue.at(_index);
        // do something with e

        if (clock::now() >= _until)
          regular();
      }
    }
  }

private:
  void regular()
  {
    // do something
    _until += std::chrono::seconds(_heartbeat_seconds);
  }

};

struct producer
{
  void run()
  {
    while(true)
    {
      // do something to get/produce an event
      event e;

      // Add the event and notify waiting bees
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
      ++queue_index;
      queue_index = queue_index % size;
      queue.at(queue_index) = e;
      cv.notify_all();
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  // create producers and bees in their individual threads and let them run free
}
```

Where you place the calls to regular() exactly depends on what you want to do if there is an event available AND the regular call is due. In the code above, the regular call takes precedence.

*Note*: IF there is risk a bee ever lags behind too much, you could increase the array size, of course, but with 0.2 seconds per event and 65536 events in the array, such a bee would lag about three and a half hours behind. So you'd be in trouble anyway. Depending on your use case, you might therefore want to add a check by comparing indexes.

Comment: Simple solution, will work unless some bee gets lagging (can crash - and comparing the indexes is not that easy, we have one on each bee... but solvable as you can see in my solution). Lot of synchronization (single mutex is less efficient for many threads if processing of events is quick and production is high), but speed of implementation and simplicity is great advantage. BTW: Using `volatile int queue_index` would do same job (used under lock, not as atomic).

Comment: @firda Each bee can compare indexes on its own (the only "difficulty" is the modulo, you need to make two cases queue_index < _index and queue_index >= _index). afaict, it could crash only if a Bee lags behind `size` entries, when copying an event which is written by the producer. If you monitor and handle extreme lagging, this is not happening. Regarding the cost synchronization: I would not make a bet right now, since I haven't thought through all the locks in your solution at http://pastebin.com/cSFs0V5Q Thanks for the volatile hint.

Answer (score 1):

**[Full code of Idea1 solution revised with spin-locking here](http://pastebin.com/1WzLV43T)** (single queue)
**[Full code of Idea2 solution here](http://pastebin.com/Y7M56Mtm)** (queue per bee)
<strike>**[Original code of Idea1 solution - not fixed agains multiple-producer race condition](http://pastebin.com/cSFs0V5Q)**</strike>

---

**The fix for multiple-producer race condition in original Idea1 solution (two reservations, but second notify/wake a bee before first producer writes the element)**

```
    size_t i = w1++;            // reserve the slot
....
    while(unlikely(             // producer spin-lock
        !w2.compare_exchange_strong(
        &i, i+1)))              // preserve reservation order
        this_thread::yield();   // pass CPU to other thread
....
    atomic<size_t> w1;          // production slot reservation
    atomic<size_t> w2;          // production signal synchronization
```

[The new code](http://pastebin.com/1WzLV43T) passed the test with 5000 produced events by 100 producers, consumed by 20 bees (100000 total). With `test_point()` being empty, no spinlocks took place (all passed without any loop on single core), same result with `yield`, but 106 written-spins with zero-sleep (prooves the concept) and 14 notify-spins (after adding `stuck=false` where it belongs). *Buzz me (by comment) if you'd like explanation of the code.*

---

### Preface

We can use semaphores + [boost::lockfree:queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html)s (per bee - **Idea2**). This won't slow down anybody too much (unlocking should be cheap, that queue does not need to be synchronized, ***we need to raise the semaphore after pushing to individual queue and try to lock/take before accessing the queue***). In fact, using mutexes for whatever queue when whe have one per bee should do just well (the time spent under lock should be small). I think that it could be possible to write both memory-efficient and time-efficient queue for this scenairo (no unnecessary locking and memory reallocation), but the question is: **is it worth it?**

Using futures (**Idea3**) is definitelly not a good solution (mutex, condition_variable, once_flag and atomic_flag per future), but **(Idea1) vector with shared_mutex** for growth and bee management (shared_lock for accessing the queue, unique_lock when we need to grow it or spawn new bees) with **per-bee-semaphore** (to make bees sleep on it) could work ([boost::lockfree::spsc_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) is actually written around vector-like structure with one read pointer and one write pointer - **we could use multiple read pointers per bee**). Solution offered ommits implementation of `push_full` (when we need to grow the queue), but passed tests with 15 producers, 10 consumers/bees and 1000 evens produced (10*1000 consumed) on QuadCore CPU.

---

### **Summary of solutions offered:**

1. **Pros:** Easy to implement, best for heavy load.
   **Cons:** Latency, active waiting, many queues.
2. **Pros:** No active waiting (event-driven).
   **Cons:** Harder to implement, many queues.
3. **Pros:** Free producers (never blocking), easier bee management.
   **Cons:** Man in the middle introduces some latency (but minimal).
4. **Pros:** Optimal memory usage. Central read-write-lock (shared_mutex) for management.
   **Cons:** Really hard to implement (reallocation especially, multiple read pointers).

**NOTE:** *This is not my original answer, especially Opt2 was rewritten and it was at first designed for load-balancing single queue. Rumburak's comments may refer to original meaning (and sometimes missunderstanding after first review). Opt3&4 were added with first review, full code for Opt4 last.*

---

[boost::lockfree:queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) is perfect candidate for this scenairo (**multi-producer multi-consumer lockfree queue**), however, we have to solve the problem of **empty queue(s)** (when consumers/bees have nothing to do) **and the fact that all bees should receive all the events** (*missed that the first time I wrote my answer*). I am taking second idea from the author for using separate queue for each bee (push like this: `for(bee& b : bees) b.push(e);`)

### **Option 1: *minimum time between events is 0.2 seconds***

We can use this information for sleep-if-no-work in bees:

```
while (!done) {
    if (time_to_do_regular())
        do_regular();
    if (queue.pop(value))
        do_work(value);
    else
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(200))
}
```

*We can reduce the sleep time to reduce **latency** it brings. This solution seems to be fine if we balance the timeout with number of bees/consumers, but adds overhead of using cpu unnecesary - this may be called **active waiting** and can slow producers down (or any other process). I prefer not to do that if we can avoid it by some wait-for-event technique.*

### **Option 2: Semaphore on each queue** (can be implemented with mutex and condition_variable).

***Regular work should be done in similar way as in option 1, but instead of active waiting we can use timed try_lock / wait_for / wait_until (with time_point for next scheduled execution).***

***COMMENT**: There were two incomplete versions here, that both were working when used as queue for one bee (multiple-producer, single consumer). Both were originally designed for load-balancing in mind (and failed in this scenairo, unfortunatelly, Rumburak keeps talking about single queue). This is the third version which aims to be complete (but all of them were actually correct for single-consumer and this approach with negative counter could be used to adapt it for load-balancing):*

**[Full code here](http://pastebin.com/Y7M56Mtm)**

```
using the_clock = chrono::steady_clock;
using stamp = chrono::time_point<the_clock>;
template<class E>
  class event_queue {
public:
    event_queue(int nbees = 64) {
        bees = new handle[this->nbees = nbees];
        for(int i = 0; i < nbees; i++)
            new(bees + i) handle();
    }
    void push(E e) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nbees; i++)
            bees[i].push(e);
    }
    bool pop(int id, E& e, stamp until) {
        return bees[id].pop(e, until);
    }
private:
    struct handle {
        atomic<int> n;  // -1 if bee is sleeping
        boost::lockfree::queue<E> q;
        mutex mx; condition_variable cv;
        bool wakeup, was_empty;
        void push(E e) {
            q.push(e);
            if(++n == 0) {
                { lock_guard<mutex> lock(mx);
                    wakeup = true; }
                cv.notify_one();
            }
        }
        bool pop(E& e, stamp until) {
            if(the_clock::now() >= until)
                return false;
            if(was_empty || --n < 0) {
                was_empty = true;
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(mx);
                if(!cv.wait_until(lock, until, [this] {
                    return wakeup; }))
                    return false;
                wakeup = false;
                was_empty = false; }
            q.pop(e);
            return true;
        }
    } *bees;
    int nbees;
};
```

### **Option 3: Man in the middle**

We can use `for (auto&& bee : bees) bee.push(event)` in producers (while implementing `event` as `shared_ptr`) but can as well use one queue for all producers ([boost::lockfree:queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) - multiple producers), one thread to pop that queue (single consumer) and fill queues of all the bees (we could use [boost::lockfree:spsc_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) - single producer, single consumer). This will slow the process a bit, but won't be slowing producers. **I still prefer option 2.**

On crash in bee, we would have to pump their queue and decrease all references on events there (or pass the queue to newly spawned bee).

### **Option 4: Single queue (fixed size now, but can be made growing)**

This was already described as **Idea1** in second paragraph of preface. Following code leaves the implementation of growing the queue (or manage bees), but suggests it can be done under unique lock (write lock). It could be further improved, but seems to work and uses less memory than Idea2/Opt2 solution.

**[Full code of Idea1 solution revised with spin-locking here](http://pastebin.com/1WzLV43T)** (single queue)
<strike>**[Original code of Idea1 solution - not fixed agains multiple-producer race condition](http://pastebin.com/cSFs0V5Q)**</strike>
**NOTE:** Revised code uses another spin-lock for `notify_all()` (changed a lot - spotted counter).

### Interface: (do regular work when pop() returns false in bees)

```
template<class E>
  class event_queue {
public:
    event_queue(size_t nbees = P, size_t bits = 10) {
    //  minimal capacity: 256, default: 1024
    //  must be power of 2 (we rather use and-mask instead of modulo)
        if(bits <= 8) bits = 8;
        size_t size = 1 << bits;
        mask = size-1; buf = a.allocate(size);
        bees = b.allocate(this->nbees = nbees);
        for(int i = 0; i < nbees; i++)
            b.construct(bees + i, *this);
    }
//  EDIT: Updated with spin-lock after construction
    void push(const E& e) {
        shared lock(sync);  // quick shared lock 
        size_t i = w1++;    // reserve the slot
        if(unlikely(i > lr+mask)) {     // check full
            push_full(i, e); return; }  // not implemented yet
        a.construct(buf+(i&mask), nbees, e); // emplace
    //  EDIT: This synchronization was added
        while(unlikely(     // producer spin-lock
            !w2.compare_exchange_strong(
            &i, i+1)))      // preserve reservation order
            this_thread::yield();       // pass CPU to other thread
    //  EDIT: SEE NEW CODE FOR BIG CHANGE HERE
        for(int i = 0; i < nbees; i++)
            bees[i].notify();
    }
    bool pop(int id, E& e, stamp until) {
        return bees[id].pop(e, until);
    }
```

### Detail:

```
private:
//  global synchronization (fast-locking unless we need to grow or manage bees)
    shared_mutex sync;
    typedef shared_lock_guard<shared_mutex> shared;
    typedef lock_guard<shared_mutex> unique;
//  consumed counting
    struct item {
        atomic<size_t> c;   // consumed countdown
        E e;            // the event/element
        item(int nbees, const E& e)
        : c(nbees), e(e) {}};
//  event buffer
    atomic<size_t> w1;  // production slot reservation
    atomic<size_t> w2;  // production signal synchronization
    atomic<size_t> lr;  // lowest read index (for each bee: bee.ri >= lr)
    size_t mask;        // element at buf[index&mask]
    item *buf;          // the buffer
    int nbees;          // number of bees
    struct handle {
        handle(event_queue<E>& q): n(0), ri(0), q(q),
          mx(), cv(), wakeup(false), was_empty(false) {}
        atomic<int> n;  // number of elements available for consumation
        int ri;         // read index
        event_queue<E>& q; // master queue
        mutex mx; condition_variable cv;
        bool wakeup, was_empty;
        void notify() {
            if(++n == 0) {
                { lock_guard<mutex> lock(mx);
                    wakeup = true; }
                cv.notify_one(); }}
        bool pop(E& e, stamp until) {
            if(the_clock::now() >= until)
                return false;
            if(was_empty || --n < 0) {
                was_empty = true;
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(mx);
                if(!cv.wait_until(lock, until, [this] {
                    return wakeup; }))
                    return false;
                wakeup = false;
                was_empty = false; }
        //  get the item
            shared lock(q.sync);
            item& i = q.buf[ri++ & q.mask];
            e = i.e;
        //  desctroy and advance lowest read index if whe were last
            if(--i.c == 0) {
                ++q.lr;
                q.a.destroy(&i); }
            return true;
        }
    } *bees;
    allocator<item> a;
    allocator<handle> b;
    void push_full(int i, const E& e) {
    //  not implemented
        assert(false);
    //  unique lock(sync); ...lot of work
        throw -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I think Option 1 adds an extra latency of 0 to 200ms, i.e. average extra 100ms before the consumer gets to discover the new information. I wonder if there is any situation where the mutex+condition overhead of option 2 is enough to make option 1 worthwhile?

Comment: To answer my own question, the 0 to 200ms latency is likely to be different for each worker bee, so when many more threads than cores it would spread the workload around nicely, and possibly end up making efficient use of the available cores.

Comment: We can decrease the time, but that would increase bees cpu-time wasting. I'd guess that timeout > bees*1ms would still do well. But for unknown number of bees and 'do it as fast as you can` scenairo, second option would be better.

Comment: About of the overhead of second option: the overhead takes place if the queues are empty, not if they are full. That is how and why I designed it that way. You don't have to think about overhead when nobody needs anything, but when you are busy, any cycle counts :)

Comment: Note about your soultions: I have used first one and enhanced it (or at least offered two solutions for problems it could bring). In your #2 you'd have to solve how to distribute messages especially when all bees are busy (that is why I preffer not to do that and use single queue). Your #3: I think that creating and destroying futures won't be good (better than my solution), in fact, it seems to be the worst modification of #1.

Comment: As mentioned before, I understood this sentence bad: *Each of these does their own processing of the events that P feeds them.* - I am not a native speaker and it looked like load-balancing problem for me at first (event consumed by first bee that can grab it). I have rewritten my answer hereafter, but with added comment that we could possibly preallocate the queue (and signal error if exceeded), we could try Opt4 - single queue with multiple read pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not aim to be perfect, but self-documenting and maintainable. It adresses other aspects of the problem - bee management. You can see counters of total production and consumation (per bee), which is used as index to the queue as well (size must be power of 2, that we can take advantage of bitwise and). Production limit can be set and monitored (incremented in push, decremented in watchdog). Bees have heartbeat (timestamp), that watchdog can use to kill them if necessary. They commit suicide automatically when they see that they missed some event (not consumed, but no longer in queue either). We can easily spot that earlier and spawn new bee if that is desired.

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using the_clock = chrono::steady_clock;
using stamp = chrono::time_point<the_clock>;
using ms = chrono::milliseconds;
using seconds = chrono::seconds;

struct event {              // the event
    int id;                 // some data
    event(const event&) = default;
    event(): id(-1) {}
    event(int id): id(id) {}
};
const size_t size = 1024;   // capacity of the queue (must be 1<<x)
event queue[size];          // buffer for the queue
size_t produced;            // number of produced events
const size_t mask = size-1; // mask for converting counters to index
mutex mx;                   // master lock for everything
condition_variable cv;      // mainly for notify_all()

size_t production_watchdog; // decrease this at constant frequency
size_t production_limit;    // we can set this on the fly
void push(const event& e) { // push the event
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mx);    // protected by global mutex
    queue[produced++ & mask] = e;   // write the element and count it
    if(production_limit             // check production limit
    && ++production_watchdog > production_limit)
        throw runtime_error("production too high");
    lock.unlock(); cv.notify_all(); // wake any sleeping bee
}

class abee {                // abstract bee (or interface to queue)
    friend void watchdog(); // watchdog can access internals
    ms timeout;             // timeout for regular function
    stamp next;             // next scheduled regular
    stamp heartbeat;        // heartbeat for watchdog
    size_t consumed;        // number of consumed events
public:
    virtual ~abee() {}      // virtual destructor (kill the thread here)
    virtual void regular() = 0;             // regular function
    virtual void consume(const event&) = 0; // consume event
    abee(): timeout(60000), next(the_clock::now() + timeout),
        heartbeat(the_clock::now()), consumed(0) {}
    abee(ms timeout): timeout(timeout), next(the_clock::now() + timeout),
        heartbeat(the_clock::now()), consumed(0) {}
    void run() {
        for(;;) {
        //  do regular job if the time is up
            if (the_clock::now() >= next) {
                heartbeat = next;   // signal that we are alive
                regular();          // do regular
                next += timeout; }  // and schedule next
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mx);
            if(!cv.wait_until(lock, next, [this] {
            //  2's complement arithmetic is our friend
                size_t avail = produced-consumed;
            //  if we are lagging, commit suicide
                if(avail >= size)
                    throw runtime_error("bee lagging");
            //  check if we have at least one to consume
                return avail > 0; }))
            //  nothing to consume
                continue;
        //  we better make a copy
            event e = queue[consumed++ & mask];
        //  now we can unlock the queue
            lock.unlock();
        //  and consume the event
            consume(e);
        }
    }
};

const int maxbees = 64;     // maximum of living bees
abee* bees[maxbees];        // list of active bees (can contain nullptrs)

void watchdog() {           // this will observe bees and kill the lagging
    seconds kill_after(90);     // maximal time we let zombie bee there
    seconds sleep_timeout(10);  // timeout before we perform our checks
    int production_decrement = 100; // should do for event per 0.1s
    for(;;) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(sleep_timeout);
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mx);
        stamp dead = the_clock::now() - kill_after;
        for(int i = 0; i < maxbees; i++) {
            abee* bee = bees[i];
            if(!bee) continue;  // deleted bee
            if(bee->heartbeat < dead) { // kill and delete
            //  place elsewhere if you don't want to delete it now ;)
                delete bee; bees[i] = nullptr;
            //  we can spawn new here
            }
        }
    //  keep production watchdog counter down
        if(production_limit
        && production_watchdog > production_decrement)
            production_watchdog -= production_decrement;
        else
            production_watchdog = 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Comments about `delete/~abee()`. Code is original.

Comment: OK, so same proposal as mine with a suggestion of how to handle lagging behind (requiring additional locking), right? Hmm. Are you sure that deleting a bee, which is running in another thread is a good idea? I am not a language lawyer, but I assume you are heading for a crash here.

Comment: That is the responsibility of the virtual destructor (that can kill the thread e.g. by pthread_kill). There was no thread introduced, neither conrete bee, thus it is up to the implementation of bee and their spawning. There is nothing bad on deleting the bee, in fact it can delete self (delete this is valid construct). if it contains the thread, it will check if detached/joined or throw exception before the actual disposing takes place (in the destructor). Your solution ommits few points, I have adressed it here.

Comment: Got it. I think you should mention that responsibility of the virtual destructor in the code comments. Otherwise those bees are in for a rough landing :-)

Comment: @Rumburak: Maybe later, maybe never. The delete does not need to be there (just an example), spawned bees does not need the pointer to this abstract bee interface (they can have their own data structure and live outside of this one, just place the pointer inside the implementation and call `the_bee->consume()/regular()`)... but the **virtual destructor** should have been obvious and if you use `class bee: public abee, public thread`, the delete will kick you (`terminate()`) if you don't kill/join the thread properly (good for testing cancelation).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, using futures (i.e. Idea 3 from my question). The advantages are that it is stable and reliable, coping well with all kinds of consumer loads, and (IMHO) quite easy to understand.

I'll start by showing how it is used:

```
int main(int,char**){
FutureType F = startProducer(900,1100);

std::thread c1 = startConsumer(F, [](const Message &result){
    //process a message
    },
    [](){
    //regular processing
    });

std::thread c2 = startConsumer(F, [](const Message &result){
    //process a message
    },
    [](){
    //regular processing
    });

c1.join();c2.join();
}
```

So, you can see each consumer defines two functions, one for the messages that the producer sends them, and one for the regular processing. (In the [full example code](https://gist.github.com/DarrenCook/8cdeca5430836a407b06) you'll see I use random sleep in the consumer threads to represent them doing work, and I start three consumer threads each with different work-loads.)

In the producer thread I use sleep to represent the wait for an external data source to send new events: the `900,1100` here means 0.9s to 1.1s between each event arriving. (In my example, the producer thread runs forever, but this is not required by this approach.)

The key to this solution is the `F` object that is passed from the producer to each of the consumers. Let's look at that, and the `Message` class, as they are closely tied:

```
class Message{
public:
  std::shared_future<Message> next;
  int a;
  std::string b;
};

typedef std::promise<Message> PromiseType;
typedef std::shared_future<Message> FutureType;
```

Here `a` and `b` represent the data payload, while `next` is an implementation detail. I used `shared_future<T>` so that we can have multiple consumers.

Here is the core of the `startProducer` function (with the random sleep and logging code elided):

```
FutureType startProducer(){
PromiseType *P = new PromiseType;
FutureType F = P -> get_future().share();

std::thread producer([](PromiseType *D){
  int cnt = 0;
  while(1){
    //Wait for data to arrive and fill in msg
    Message msg;
    msg.a = ...;
    msg.b = ...;

    //Prepare for next message
    PromiseType *P2 = new PromiseType;
    msg.next = P2->get_future().share();

    //Broadcast the message
    P->set_value( std::move(msg) );

    //Tidy-up, ready for next iteration
    delete P;
    P = P2;
    }
  }, P);

producer.detach();  //Run forever

return F;
}
```

This is where the *key idea* happens: before broadcasting (using `set_value`) each data payload that comes in, we create a new `std::promise` and store a `std::shared_future` handle to it in the message we send out. That new `std::promise` then replaces the previous one we had.

At the other end of this data flow we have the consumer threads. I'll start by showing a simple consumer, that doesn't have to handle the "regular processing" requirement of the original question:

```
std::thread startConsumer(FutureType F,
  std::function<void(const Message&)> processing){
std::thread consumer([=](FutureType F){
  while(true){
    Message msg = F.get();
    processing(msg);
    F = std::move( msg.next );
    }
  }, std::move(F));
return consumer;
}
```

A consumer thread just has to call `F.get()` on the future. Then process it. Then extract out `msg.next` to get the next message to process. If a consumer takes a long time to process something the messages will queue up (that queue is behaving like a linked-list).

Going back to the regular processing requirement, in [my full example](https://gist.github.com/DarrenCook/8cdeca5430836a407b06) I'm using a fixed, global, regular processing interval of 15 seconds:

```
int regularProcessingDeltaInSeconds = 15;
```

but it could actually be per-consumer thread.

Here is what `startConsumer()` looks like:

```
std::thread startConsumer(FutureType F, 
  std::function<void(const Message&)> processing,
  std::function<void()> regularProcessing
  ){

std::thread consumer([=](FutureType F){
  time_t t2 = ((int)( time(NULL) /regularProcessingDeltaInSeconds)+1)*regularProcessingDeltaInSeconds; //Round up to next interval
  auto nextMinute = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(t2);
  while(true){
    auto waitResult = F.wait_until(nextMinute);

    if(waitResult == std::future_status::timeout){
      regularProcessing();
      nextMinute += std::chrono::seconds(regularProcessingDeltaInSeconds);
      continue;
      }
    else if(waitResult != std::future_status::ready){  //No time-out,
      //but cannot call get() yet either. (Implies a spurious wake-up?)
      continue;
      }

    if(std::chrono::system_clock::now() > nextMinute){
      //If we've got data from producer, but it is also time to do regular processing,
      //  give the regular processing priority.
      regularProcessing();
      nextMinute += std::chrono::seconds(regularProcessingDeltaInSeconds);
      }

    Message result = F.get();
    processing(result);
    F = std::move( result.next );
    }
  }, std::move(F));

return consumer;
}
```

(The complicated first line is because `std::chrono` has no built-in function to round up to the start of the next interval.)

Before `get()` we now call `wait_until()`, and call `regularProcessing()` if it is time for the next regular interval before the next message from the data producer arrives.

I violate the DRY principle here, with two calls to `regularProcessing()`, each followed by the same code to update `nextMinute`. This is needed because if a consumer is slow, and always has stuff to process in its queue, then `wait_until()` always returns `ready` and never returns `timeout`, meaning that `regularProcessing()` would never get called. So before calling `get()` we also have to check the clock.

(Alternatives to avoid duplicating those couple of lines ended up worse overall.)

That is it. You can see [full working code you can play with here](https://gist.github.com/DarrenCook/8cdeca5430836a407b06).

The next step would be for the producer to add a nano-second accuracy timestamp on the data, and then have each consumer thread report latency: how long it took to get hold of each message. Totalling that over a few hundred runs should give a good basis to compare its efficiency with alternative solutions that use explicit queues and mutexes.

---

Here is some example output. You can see how 'c3-erratic' is consuming data more slowly than it is being produced, but always gets there in the end.

```
Producer: next data will arrive in 900ms...
Producer: new data arrived, so about to set result (cnt=1)
Producer: next data will arrive in 926ms...
     c1-fast:result.a=1,b=2014-08-16 12:21:28 (took 0ms to calculate)
Producer: new data arrived, so about to set result (cnt=2)
Producer: next data will arrive in 1051ms...
     c1-fast:result.a=2,b=2014-08-16 12:21:29 (took 0ms to calculate)
     c2-slow:result.a=1,b=2014-08-16 12:21:28 (took 944ms to calculate)
     c3-erratic:result.a=1,b=2014-08-16 12:21:28 (took 1116ms to calculate)
     c1-fast:PER-MINUTE PROCESSING, will take 491ms...
     c1-fast:per-minute processing, DONE!
     c2-slow:result.a=2,b=2014-08-16 12:21:29 (took 979ms to calculate)
     c2-slow:PER-MINUTE PROCESSING, will take 553ms...
Producer: new data arrived, so about to set result (cnt=3)
Producer: next data will arrive in 992ms...
     c1-fast:result.a=3,b=2014-08-16 12:21:30 (took 0ms to calculate)
     c2-slow:per-minute processing, DONE!
Producer: new data arrived, so about to set result (cnt=4)
Producer: next data will arrive in 1007ms...
     c1-fast:result.a=4,b=2014-08-16 12:21:31 (took 0ms to calculate)
     c3-erratic:result.a=2,b=2014-08-16 12:21:29 (took 2098ms to calculate)
     c3-erratic:PER-MINUTE PROCESSING, will take 452ms...
     c2-slow:result.a=3,b=2014-08-16 12:21:30 (took 943ms to calculate)
     c3-erratic:per-minute processing, DONE!
Producer: new data arrived, so about to set result (cnt=5)
Producer: next data will arrive in 944ms...
     c1-fast:result.a=5,b=2014-08-16 12:21:32 (took 0ms to calculate)
```

Comment: My opinion is, that any working solution will do (the most-slowing part will remain the same). That means, that you can use any of them that fits you, that you understand and gets the job done for you. This solution will probably have the worst performance (creating new future for every message, heavy synchronization), but if you like it, why not? **Easy maintainance and time to implement is often more important than tiny run-speed difference (and memory usage).** My Idea1/Opt4 with spinlocks should be fastest, but maybe not the best for beeing too complex :)

Comment: BTW: You cannot get any other status than timeout/ready from your futures (deffered is not aplicable here, no other is possible). That check can be removed. (You can call get for deferred state, thus timeout or any other is fine test even with deferred async.)

Comment: @firda Re: deferred. Thanks: Not understanding the docs (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_status ) I'd assumed it meant a spurious wake-up. But when does deferred happen then? (I cannot find anything on google so far!)

Comment: See [async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) [launch::deferred](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch).

Comment: Nice idea! I have no idea about synchronization costs for shared_futures. Have tried to do measurements? In general, I haven't found much information about shared_futures, but this is a nice example for using them!

Comment: shared_future is in fact shared_ptr to internal_state, which has mutex, condition_variabe and few flags (once_flag and atomic_flag). This explains why is your solution working - the state gets deleted once no reference exist - once last bee consumes the message. The creation of the mutex + condition_variable and allocation/destruction of shared state is slowing it down, but as I have already told you, that slow-down won't bee too big compared to expected work in bees, so, use it if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer, but additional information to the topic based on comments

I may edit it with other benchmarks related to topic ;)**

---

[I have done some *benchmarks* (full code here)](http://pastebin.com/7YMvEpy9), but on old PC
(**single core**, Cygwin 32bit on XP, don't have access to QuadCore now):

```
                   single   8 thrs  64 thrs  256 th.
lockfree spsc:     3.984s    N/A      N/A      N/A
lockfree multi:    7.250s   4.672s   6.281s   8.703s
mutex+deque:       6.531s   3.797s   5.141s   7.859s
mutex+circular:    6.516s   3.969s   5.125s   7.984s
mutex+space_cb:    6.938s   4.234s   5.531s   8.109s
spin+deque:        4.109s   2.000s   3.250s   6.500s
spin+circular:     4.219s   2.172s   3.344s   6.703s
spin+space_cb:     4.609s   2.422s   3.672s   6.750s
```

You can notice that *boost::lockfree::queue* was the worst (could be because of **single core**), but *boost::lockfree::spsc_queue* outperfomed the other queues quite well (in SPSC scenairo, ***this may be good hint for both Idea1 and Idea2 solutions***). This was simple *push many, pop many* test, no sleeping, no waking up. But you can use the code (especially [boost::timer::cpu_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html)) to do other benchmarks for the solution.

**Spinlock with yield** (see the code) instead of mutex can improve the performance quite well as you can see ;)

**Full Output:** (**W**all Clock = external clock, **T**otal = **U**ser + **S**ystem = true CPU time)

```
simple push many, pop many:
  boost::lockfree::spsc_queue:
    W:  4.050s, T:  3.984s (U:  3.984s, S: 0.000s, 98.4%)
  boost::lockfree::queue (preallocated):
    W:  7.400s, T:  7.250s (U:  7.156s, S: 0.094s, 98.0%)
  std::deque + std::mutex:
    W:  6.661s, T:  6.531s (U:  6.531s, S: 0.000s, 98.1%)
  boost::circular_buffer + std::mutex:
    W:  6.622s, T:  6.516s (U:  6.516s, S: 0.000s, 98.4%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + std::mutex:
    W:  7.026s, T:  6.938s (U:  6.938s, S: 0.000s, 98.7%)
  std::deque + spinlock with yield:
    W:  4.175s, T:  4.109s (U:  4.109s, S: 0.000s, 98.4%)
  boost::circular_buffer + spinlock with yield:
    W:  4.328s, T:  4.219s (U:  4.219s, S: 0.000s, 97.5%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + spinlock with yield:
    W:  4.674s, T:  4.609s (U:  4.609s, S: 0.000s, 98.6%)
8 threads push many, pop many:
  boost::lockfree::queue (preallocated):
    W:  4.778s, T:  4.672s (U:  4.250s, S: 0.422s, 97.8%)
  std::deque + std::mutex:
    W:  3.900s, T:  3.797s (U:  3.562s, S: 0.234s, 97.4%)
  boost::circular_buffer + std::mutex:
    W:  4.067s, T:  3.969s (U:  3.734s, S: 0.234s, 97.6%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + std::mutex:
    W:  4.364s, T:  4.234s (U:  4.062s, S: 0.172s, 97.0%)
  std::deque + spinlock with yield:
    W:  2.040s, T:  2.000s (U:  1.766s, S: 0.234s, 98.0%)
  boost::circular_buffer + spinlock with yield:
    W:  2.318s, T:  2.172s (U:  1.859s, S: 0.312s, 93.7%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + spinlock with yield:
    W:  2.463s, T:  2.422s (U:  2.156s, S: 0.266s, 98.3%)
64 threads push many, pop many:
  boost::lockfree::queue (preallocated):
    W:  6.779s, T:  6.281s (U:  3.953s, S: 2.328s, 92.7%)
  std::deque + std::mutex:
    W:  5.425s, T:  5.141s (U:  3.406s, S: 1.734s, 94.8%)
  boost::circular_buffer + std::mutex:
    W:  5.490s, T:  5.125s (U:  3.422s, S: 1.703s, 93.4%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + std::mutex:
    W:  5.860s, T:  5.531s (U:  3.797s, S: 1.734s, 94.4%)
  std::deque + spinlock with yield:
    W:  3.678s, T:  3.250s (U:  1.656s, S: 1.594s, 88.4%)
  boost::circular_buffer + spinlock with yield:
    W:  3.720s, T:  3.344s (U:  1.500s, S: 1.844s, 89.9%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + spinlock with yield:
    W:  3.951s, T:  3.672s (U:  2.000s, S: 1.672s, 92.9%)
256 threads push many, pop many:
  boost::lockfree::queue (preallocated):
    W:  9.648s, T:  8.703s (U:  3.688s, S: 5.016s, 90.2%)
  std::deque + std::mutex:
    W:  8.733s, T:  7.859s (U:  3.250s, S: 4.609s, 90.0%)
  boost::circular_buffer + std::mutex:
    W:  8.718s, T:  7.984s (U:  2.922s, S: 5.062s, 91.6%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + std::mutex:
    W:  9.056s, T:  8.109s (U:  3.312s, S: 4.797s, 89.5%)
  std::deque + spinlock with yield:
    W:  7.395s, T:  6.500s (U:  1.844s, S: 4.656s, 87.9%)
  boost::circular_buffer + spinlock with yield:
    W:  7.482s, T:  6.703s (U:  1.906s, S: 4.797s, 89.6%)
  boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized + spinlock with yield:
    W:  7.806s, T:  6.750s (U:  1.969s, S: 4.781s, 86.5%)
```

**NOTE:** I have placed warning on my original answer for **race condition on Idea1 with multiple producers**. It can be avoided with spin-like approach (second write pointer - see updated answer). Such *optimistic* solution may outperform those with heavy-sync, but are not easy to write. I am doing my own research now, for my own reasons (my linux server) and will try to post relevant results here. Feel free to stop me if it gets out of topic ;)